# wordpress get current user without wp-load.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently trying to write a couple of pages into my website that are not part of the wordpress site but I would like to be able to use the wordpress users. I have this working using the following code

```
require_once("../../../wp-load.php");
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

Now I am able to use the $current_user variable for everything I need. However because I am includeing the wp-load.php file there is a lot of overhead that I really don't need.

My question is how can I get the current wordpress user without including wp-load?

I don't mind having to include a few extra files myself but I really don't need or want the entire wp enviroment to be set-up each time this page is called just so I can get the user.

Comment: You can  try this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-get-current-user-id-outside-of-wp-blog#post-820219

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing in those pages? I'm asking because, if you want to send some POST via ajax, you should check [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side).

If you don't use ajax, but you just need some pages where you can acces Wordpress functions, well somehow you must include wp-load because this file is loading Wordpress.

I suggest creating a file called page-custom-name.php in your theme folder, and publish an empty page with the exact title "Custom-name". Now when you'll be visiting www.yoursite/custom-name you will see that page, and you can get the current user info, or access other Wordpress functions.

Later edit:

This idea a partial solution: How about using hooks?

In your functions.php put these lines:

```
add_action('wp_login', 'aboutuser');

function aboutuser($username, $user)
{
  $userObject = $user;

  //find a solution to send this data to your url of your application
}
```

Basically, when users are logging in Wordpress, the aboutuser() function is executed, and it's get 2 params(in Wordpress 3.3; in earlier versions it gets only the username).

Now, when users are logging in we have acces to the wp user object. Maybe there is a way pass this data(a POST request) to your application and store it in a session.

I don't sure if it's possible though.

Comment: This is actually a work project. We have a seperate application already setup outside of wordpress. I have added functionality to the application to create posts into the wordpress system so I need to make sure that the visitor is logged into the wordpress system and that they are allowed to make posts. for the page that actually creates the post it is fine that I include the wp-load.php because I need to be able to call the functions to create posts and add comments. However loading the entire wp environment on the main page just to check if the visitor is logged into wordpress is overkill.

Comment: Well, I'm not quite sure about the differences between including wp-load, or setting a page like I said. However, including wp-load is not really a good idea http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article, but it is mostly talking about plugins and the main problem it points out is that the wp envirnoment would be loaded twice. This is not the case with what I am doing since the application is not running within wp. The main reason I was looking for a solution to this was that including wp-load.php was causing some of the functionality in our application to fail. I have since found a solution to that problem (although I still don't fully understand why the problem existed). Still would be nice to know how to get just the user information though.

Comment: check my edited answer, it's just an idea, sorry if i'm wrong :)